# In R, why is v[length(v)+1] = x better than c(v, x)?

Tags: r

I wrote the following two functions, one to test increasing vector size using concatenate, and one using brackets:

```
c_test <- function(n) {
  cv = c()
  for(i in 1:n) cv = c(cv, i)
  cv
  }

b_test <- function(n) {
  bv = c()
  for (i in 1:n) bv[i] = i
  bv
  }

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(c_test(1e+4), b_test(1e+4), times = 100)

#Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
# c_test(10000) 140.27923 145.73282 156.82319 148.16175 151.74713 267.2393   100
# b_test(10000)  49.58033  54.42992  56.24268  54.86033  56.30862 132.8394   100
```

This is a big time difference, and I don't understand why using brackets is so much better than using concatenate. It seems like in both cases it would be taking time to allocate new memory, but this doesn't seem true. I also thought it might be that `c(v, x)` is converting up `x` to be the same type as `v` before merging, but saying `v[i] = as.vector(x)` isn't a significant time cost.

Comment: one thing to note here is that this behavior flips for low values of `my_len`, which suggests what's really going on. The latter looks as though it pre-allocates a certain amount of extra space for that vector to grow, while the former always creates a copy. Pre-allocating will be slower at small sizes than copying.

Comment: Actually flips right around `mylen` in the range 800-900

Comment: Both are bad if used in a `for` loop without preallocation. R is built around vectorized functions to avoid these time penalties.

Comment: If iteration is necessary (usually it is not -- vectorize instead) then it's much better to pre-allocate and fill `bv = integer(my_len); ... bv[i] = i` or just let R manage memory during iteration via `lapply()` / `vapply()`, etc.

Comment: @Shape So then the empty vector `c()` implicitly pre-allocates memory space? And if that's the case, why would the switch occur? Wouldn't it still fill in efficiently more so than copying repeatedly?

@MartinMorgan @alistaire Yeah, this came out of writing fibonacci for fib values less than n. Can't vectorize that, and wondering about solutions that don't pre-allocate a vector.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Even if we don't consider vectorization both approaches are terribly inefficient. Preallocate, preallocate, preallocate. No, really, preallocate.

Comment: @Roland Agreed, but it looks like the latter actually is pre-allocating, admittedly, it's one-size-fits-all pre-allocating which doesn't fit with his problem. But if I didn't know exactly how big `my_len` was likely to be, having some standard pre-allocation doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: No, it's not preallocating.

Comment: I believe the difference is the overhead for S3 method dispatch but I'm on my phone and can't check. Try with c.default.

Comment: And growing an object gets more expensive with increasing size.

Comment: @Shape That doesn't bypass method dispatch.

Comment: @Roland yeah, should have checked my outputs, was just returning the primitive. how do I access the default c method? `getS3Method` and `methods` seem to give me an unusual set of classes.

Comment: @Shape You can't. Dispatch is done internally in the C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should probably be a comment as I don't know the actual answer, but it was getting too long.

"c" and "[" are both primitive, internal and generic.  This means method dispatch is done by C functions, and that's as far as I can get in answering your actual question.  Something mysterious is going on there, and "[" is more efficient than "c" in this particular respect.

However, I did want to point out that, as per some but not all of the comments, both these methods are inefficient and not just on account of vectorisation.  Preallocating memory space for the size of the vector you expect does help very materially, much more so than the difference between `c` and `[`.  Preallocation gives you a 70% to 90% speed up from the `[` version:

```
# very poor - repeated calls to c() to extend
c_test <- function(n) {
  cv = c()
  for(i in 1:n) cv = c(cv, i)
  cv
}

# slightly better - just use []
b_test <- function(n) {
  bv = c()
  for (i in 1:n) bv[i] = i
  bv
}

# much better practice - preallocate length of the vector
d_test <- function(n) {
  bv = numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) bv[i] = i
  bv
}

# good practice if possible - vectorisation
e_test <- function(n) {
  bv = 1:n
  bv
}


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(c_test(1e+4), b_test(1e+4), d_test(1e+4), e_test(1e+4), times = 100)
```

This gives:

```
Unit: microseconds
          expr        min         lq         mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 c_test(10000) 102355.753 111202.568 129250.53638 114237.234 132468.938 220005.926   100   c
 b_test(10000)  47337.481  52820.938  77029.01728  59450.864 116529.185 192643.555   100  b 
 d_test(10000)   6761.877   7492.741   7965.37288   7814.519   8353.778  11007.605   100 a  
 e_test(10000)      3.555      6.321      9.32347      8.692     10.272     27.259   100 a
```

Also, as @Roland said "growing an object gets more expensive with increasing size".  As the vector gets bigger there are less convenient spots available in memory to put it.

I appreciate that the `e_test` (vectorised) isn't applicable in your Fibonacci use case but left it in for comparison anyway, to give an idea of the scale of speed up when vectorisation is possible.

Comment: If you look at the [code of do_c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/bind.c) you see a comment that all arguments are evaluated and checked for method dispatch. For subsetting the check is much simpler since only one argument needs to be checked. Also, I contest OP's assertion that they can't pre-allocate in their use case. You can always guess a size and grow in chunks as necessary. I have recently written a Fibonacci implementation that might be of interest to OP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41323414/1412059

Comment: Thanks @Roland, very useful re do_c.  And I agree really pre-allocation. If you have a for loop you can obviously do it.  If it is a while loop you can still guess.

Comment: @Roland If I gave the impression that pre-allocation couldn't happen here, I didn't mean to say that. I personally avoid pre-allocation most of the time, but only for stupid reasons (shameful, I know). I just started in R, so your Fibonacci code is useful as I was just wondering how memoization can be implemented, and it's extra interesting to see that functions can be nested.