# R: converting a while loop to recursion

Tags: r, loops, recursion

**I'm trying to convert a `while` loop to a recursion.**

I know the while loop is more efficient, but I'm trying to understand how to convert a `for/while` loop to recursion, and recursion to a `for/while/if` loop.

**my function as I'm using a `while` loop:**

```
       harmon_sum <- function(x){
      n <- 1
      sum <- 0
      while (sum < x) 
      {
        sum <- sum + (1/n)
        n <- (n +1)
      }
      return(n)
    }
```

This function takes some numeric value, suppose `x=2`, and returns the number of objects for the harmonic sum that you need to sum up  in order to create a greater number then x. (for x=2, you'd need to sum up the first **5** objects of the harmonic sum)

```
 [![harmonic sum][1]][1]





**example**: `harmon_sum <- function(x){
   n <- 1
   sum <- 0
   while (sum < x) 
   {
     sum <- sum + (1/n)
     print(sum)
     n <- (n +1)
   print(n)
     }
   return(n)
 }

> harmon_sum(x =2)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 1.5
[1] 3
[1] 1.833333
[1] 4
[1] 2.083333
[1] 5
[1] 5`
```

**my version for the recursive function:**

```
    harmon_sum2 <- function(x, n =1){
   if( x<= 0){
    return(n-1)
    }
  else {
    x <- (x- (1/(n)))
    harmon_sum2(x, n+1)
  }
}
```

which returns me the wrong answer. 
I'd rather find a solution with just one variable (x), instead of using two variables (x, n), but I couldn't figure a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that if you change `return(n-1)` to `return(n)` you do get the right results.

```
harmon_sum2 <- function(x, n=1){
  if( x <= 0){
    return(n)
  }
  else {
    x <- (x- (1/(n)))
    harmon_sum2(x, n+1)
  }
}

harmon_sum(2)
[1] 5
harmon_sum2(2)
[1] 5
harmon_sum(4)
[1] 32
harmon_sum2(4)
[1] 32
```

Comment: is it possible to define the function where the input is consisted only in x?

I mean, `harmon_sum2 <- function(x)`

I know it must be possible because of the Church-Turing thesis

Comment: I wouldn't know about that. To me it seems like you need to keep track of `n` as well. @Roland gives a solution for this. Otherwise, you could try to ask a new question for this. Maybe the sister website on theoretical computer science will be a better place to ask: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your function needs to know `n`. If you don't want to pass it, you need to store it somewhere where all functions on the call stack can access it. For your specific case you can use `sys.nframe` instead:

```
harmon_sum2 <- function(x){
  if( x<= 0){
    return(sys.nframe())
  }
  else {
    x <- (x- (1/(sys.nframe())))
    harmon_sum2(x)
  }
}

harmon_sum(8)
#[1] 1675
harmon_sum2(8)
#[1] 1675
```

However, this doesn't work if you call your function from within another function:

```
print(harmon_sum2(8))
#[1] 4551
```

Another alternative is the approach I demonstrate in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41323414/1412059).

Comment: but that returns a false answer

Comment: It returns the same answer as your original function?

Comment: It returns 5 on my system.